# How do you run an R program from Java?

Tags: java, r

I have program written with R. I can run it from the R GUI and it spits out results.

Is there a way to run that program from Java?

Comment: RCaller uses Runtime.exec in a more sophisticated way @HotLicks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at these three projects.

- [JRI - Java/R Interface](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/)
- [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/)
- [RCaller](http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php)

Comment: A comparative entry page and a paper are:



  [1]: http://stdioe.blogspot.com/2013/08/a-user-document-for-rcaller.html
  [2]: http://sciencedomain.org/download/NDgzOEBAcGY

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the easiest possibilities to execute R code from some other environment is REST webservice.

For instance if you have an R-Script called example.R with the following function:

```
#* @get /hello
hello <- function() {
  print("hello")
}
```

You can run the following:

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("example.R")
r$run(port=8080)
```

If you then call the page

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

your R code will be executed.

If you want to execute it from Java the solution could be:

```
   URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/hello");
   URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( (connection.getInputStream())));
   String result = br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [FastR](https://github.com/oracle/fastr), which is R engine implemented on top of JVM. Using it from Java is as simple as:

```
Context context = Context.newBuilder("R").allowAllAccess(true).build();
int result = context.eval("R", "sum").execute(new int[] {3,4,5}).asInt();
context.eval("R", "print('you can eval any R code here');");
```

[This is an example](https://github.com/graalvm/examples/blob/master/r_java_embedding) of how to pass data from Java to R and make it look like a `data.frame`. [This is another example](https://github.com/graalvm/examples/tree/master/fastr_javaui) of how to redirect R graphics into Java `Graphics2D` object.

A more detailed description is in this article: https://medium.com/graalvm/faster-r-with-fastr-4b8db0e0dceb

and on the GraalVM website: http://graalvm.org