# How to load R scripts in Java without installing R?

Tags: java, r, maven

I have a R script that reads data from an excel, runs it through some models and then puts the output into another excel. I need to add a function into my Java program that can make the same as that script.

I looked at all the options out there but all of them gave me some kind of trouble. First I tried rJava but my program runs at another server and it crashed because "Cannot find JRI native library!". So I guess that I need to have R in the server and sadly that is not an option.

So I found Renjin to use R without needing R installed. But the problem is that it need JSE 1.8 or greater and my program runs in 1.6. Again, and sadly, upgrading to 1.8 is not an option.

Is there any other option that can work in my situation? Another libraries or a way to chante the models in someway that allows me to use them in Java? Thanks in advance

Comment: Java 1.6 is ancient.  Time to upgrade.

Comment: Here are some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319067/how-do-you-run-an-r-program-from-java